# Automatically block out time in Outlook calendar with meetings booked in G-suit

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, google-workspace, google-sync

My work uses G-Suit/Google Workspace to manage email and calendars, and my client prefers to book meetings with Outlook. This leads to me being double booked fairly often, and I spend a lot of time updating each calendar to some sort of synchronization, but meetings get moved around a lot so I'm nearly always out of date.

I'm looking for a low friction way to block out time in my Outlook calendar when I have meetings booked in G-suit.

I've looked at Google Workspace Sync for Microsoft Outlook, but it seems like overkill, and I don't want to sync emails or all the meeting details as there is some potential of details relating to other clients, or sensitive internal details being contained in meeting invites, and I don't want to send that to the clients systems. This may also rule out Auto forwarding meeting invites.

This may not be possible, but I'd appreciate any ideas help me get double booked less often.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think, the Auto forwarding meeting invites method should be the best workaround for your issue. While the question now is that you do not would like your meeting details been forwarded at the same time for security. What I can find is that maybe we can use VBA scripts along with the Auto forwarding rules to forward the meeting invitations you  received and remove its meeting details. I'm not expert of scripting but found a similar thread: [Automatically Forward Emails and Remove/Replace All or Part of Body](https://forums.slipstick.com/threads/96165-automatically-forward-emails-and-remove-replace-all-or-part-of-body/).

Guess that should worth a shot.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Regards~

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in 20 minutes by setting up a Zapier account and using the following workflow:

1. When a new or updated event is detected in my Google Calendar account
2. Zap filter: And the organizer's email address does not contain the same domain as the calendar on which I want to block time (avoid duplicating events if the organizer invited both your work and personal) - this filter requires a paid account as it's considered multi-step.
3. Then add a new event title "Blocked" matching the start/end times of the original event.

This was the first time I actually used Zapier for something useful. Hope this helps you guys!